# Using Javascript on css3 forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Using a JavaScript+jQuery I am manipulating image widths as so:

JAVASCRIPT

```
var imageWidth = .9 * $(window).innerWidth();
var imageHeight = .6 * $(window).innerWidth();

$("document").ready(function(){
    $(".class").css("width",imageWidth);
    $(".class").css("height",imageHeight);
});
```

But I also am using this to give my submit button a PHP robust image

CSS

```
 form input[type=submit]{
     background: url("xyz.png") no-repeat center center;
     width: 90px;
     height: 60px;
     border: none;
     color: transparent;
     font-size:0;
 }
```

(more on this css technique at www.suburban-glory.com/blog?page=140)

My question is not very difficult but I can't find the information I need. How do I call the form input `[type=submit]` in JavaScript so I can manipulate the image used for the submit button? (as you can see in the examples I was simply calling CSS classes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('form input[type="submit"]').css('background-image', 'url("xyz.png")');
```

Comment: by the way I don-t want to change or set the url via javascript, I am changing the css height and width properties. I'll substitute the last phrase..

Comment: well you can change any css property by using the css method in jquery